# Image alignment in Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

When I insert an image in [Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver): how do I align it freely like move and place the image wherever I want istead of using the alignments?

Comment: More of a http://superuser.com question I feel.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a "div" element and put your image inside of it.

Or you can set style of the image as "position absolute".

Comment: how can i create a div element

Comment: sorry, i dont have a Dreamweaver installed right now. So, i cant guide you through that, but i can help you with the code if you like. There should be some 'code view' section in Dreamweaver. You can add <div style="position:absolute"><img src="yourimage.jpg" /></div> . Dont forget, you need to add this inside body tags. After that, when you go back to user interface, you should see your div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use align attribute in HTML code in the div tag.

```
<div align="center">
  This is some text!
</div>
```

Comment: He's asking for a way to move images freely WITHOUT using alignments

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use a div with its property of float(either left or right)

You can use in such a way as follows:

```
<div id="xyz" style="float : left; position:relative">
   hello world
</div>
```